VBA Macro - CopyPaste on clipboard slowing down macro - how to circumvent copying
First of all, its completely functional but the time it takes to complete is 10-20 seconds and will trigger numerous clipboard issues. I'm a complete amateur with VBA macros, but I managed to make it work somehow, if you make suggestions please assume I'm 5 years old.
The function of the macro is to match a current and a new article in a column and match it to equally named article in a different sheet. Then it has to create a table in a 3rd sheet and return values if they are different from each other. Right now it's doing it through CopyPaste and I feel like I have hit the limit of my capabilities of blunt forcing this.
Sub CreateRebuidlistOptima()
    Sheets("RebuildPrintOptima").DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    StartRow = 2 'Row to start on for printable rebuild sheet
    
    '1. Clear printable rebuild sheet
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Range("A1:A500").EntireRow.Clear
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    '1. end
    
    '2. Define the article nr for rebuild
    Worksheets("RebuildPage").Select
    CurrentArticle = Worksheets("RebuildPage").Cells(9, 4)
    NewArticle = Worksheets("RebuildPage").Cells(11, 4)
    
    Set FoundArticle = Worksheets("RebuildPage").Range("P3:P100").Find(What:=CurrentArticle, LookIn:=xlValues)
    CurrentArticleRow = FoundArticle.Row
    CurrentArticle = Worksheets("RebuildPage").Cells(CurrentArticleRow, 18)
    
    Set FoundArticle = Worksheets("RebuildPage").Range("P3:P100").Find(What:=NewArticle, LookIn:=xlValues)
    NewArticleRow = FoundArticle.Row
    NewArticle = Worksheets("RebuildPage").Cells(NewArticleRow, 18)
    '2. end
    
    '3. Define Columns for chosen articles
    Set FoundArticle = Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Range("H4:AZ4").Find(What:=CurrentArticle, LookIn:=xlValues)
    CurrentArticleColumn = FoundArticle.Column
    
    Set FoundArticle = Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Range("H4:AZ4").Find(What:=NewArticle, LookIn:=xlValues)
    NewArticleColumn = FoundArticle.Column
    '3. End
    
    '4. Get header rebuild list
    Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Range("A5:I5").Copy
        Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteColumnWidths)
    Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(5, CurrentArticleColumn).Copy
        Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 10).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 10).PasteSpecial (xlPasteColumnWidths)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(5, NewArticleColumn).Copy
        Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 11).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 11).PasteSpecial (xlPasteColumnWidths)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '4. End
    
    '5. Loop which rows to include
        ' i is the first row of the rebuild list to check
    i = 6
    Do Until i = 100
        If Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(i, 9) = "I" Then ' always show
        CopyRow = 1
        Else
            If Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(i, 9) = "N" Then ' never show
            CopyRow = 0
            Else
                If Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(i, CurrentArticleColumn) = Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(i, NewArticleColumn) Then 'return value if different
                CopyRow = 0
                Else
                CopyRow = 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    
        If CopyRow = 1 Then
        StartRow = StartRow + 1
                    
        Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Range("A" & i, "I" & i).Copy
            Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(i, CurrentArticleColumn).Copy
            Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 10).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(i, NewArticleColumn).Copy
            Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Cells(StartRow, 11).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    
        CheckNextRow = i + 1
        If Worksheets("RebuildMatrixOptima").Cells(CheckNextRow, 1) = "" Then
        i = 100
        Else
        i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
    '5. End
    
    '6 Hide Unnecessary columns
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Range("B:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Range("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Range("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Range("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    '6 End
    
    Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("RebuildPrintOptima").DisplayPageBreaks = True
    End Sub`

Pretty much reached the end of my abilities

Currently, you are using xlPasteAll, which will not only copy the data but also the formatting. Do you need that or is it sufficient to copy only the data?

First thing to state is working code is better displayed on CodeReview, as StackOverflow has a different MO.
Recognizing you're using xlPasteColumnWidths, i assume some of the formatting is important... but you can format at the end, and in other manners that aren't pastespecial.  Other options to speed up are destination.value = source.value, application.enableevents = false, or working with arrays and transposing data rather than interacting with the sheets for each step.

I would disagree that CodeReview is "better" - traffic there is super-low compared to here, so I would guess SO is better with respect to number of folks likely to see your question.  Working code is not off-topic here on SO, if there's some specific issue or problem you're trying to fix, such as slowness for example.

Maybe add some timing into your code to see which part is taking the longest, and concentrate on that.  I'd also suggest cleaning up your code by decalring and using some worksheet variables, so you can write (eg) wsRPO instead of 100 x Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima") - that just adds bulk to your code and distracts from the core logic.

This question is similar to: How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Option Explicit

Sub CreateRebuidlistOptima()
    
    Dim wsPrint As Worksheet, wsPage As Worksheet, wsMatrix As Worksheet
    Dim CurrentArticle As String, NewArticle As String
    Dim CurrentArticleColumn As Long, NewArticleColumn As Long
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim bCopyRow As Boolean, startrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
     
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsPrint = .Sheets("RebuildPrintOptima")
        Set wsPage = .Sheets("RebuildPage")
        Set wsMatrix = .Sheets("RebuildMatrixOptima")
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    startrow = 2 'Row to start on for printable rebuild sheet
    
    '1. Clear printable rebuild sheet
    With wsPrint
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False
        .Range("A1:A500").EntireRow.Clear
        .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With
    '1. end
    
    '2. Define the article nr for rebuild
    With wsPage
        CurrentArticle = .Range("D9")
        NewArticle = .Range("D11")
        With .Range("P3:P100")
            Set rngFound = .Find(What:=CurrentArticle, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox CurrentArticle & " not found in P3:P100", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            Else
                CurrentArticle = rngFound.Offset(, 2) 'col 18 R
            End If
            
            Set rngFound = .Find(What:=NewArticle, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox NewArticle & " not found in P3:100", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            Else
                NewArticle = rngFound.Offset(, 2) 'col 18 R
            End If
        End With
    End With
    '2. end
    
    With wsMatrix
        '3. Define Columns for chosen articles
        With .Range("H4:AZ4")
            Set rngFound = .Find(What:=CurrentArticle, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox CurrentArticle & " not found in H4:AZ4", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            Else
                CurrentArticleColumn = rngFound.Column
            End If
        
            Set rngFound = .Find(What:=NewArticle, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox NewArticle & " not found in H4:AZ4", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            Else
                NewArticleColumn = rngFound.Column
            End If
        End With
        '3. End
    
        '4. Get header rebuild list
        .Cells(5, 1).Resize(1, 9).Copy wsPrint.Cells(startrow, 1)
        .Cells(5, CurrentArticleColumn).Copy wsPrint.Cells(startrow, 10)
        .Cells(5, NewArticleColumn).Copy wsPrint.Cells(startrow, 11)
        '4. End
    
        '5. Loop which rows to include
        ' i is the first row of the rebuild list to check
        i = 6
        Do Until i = 100 Or .Cells(i, 1) = ""
            If .Cells(i, 9) = "I" Then ' always show
                bCopyRow = True
            Else
                If .Cells(i, 9) = "N" Then ' never show
                    bCopyRow = False
                Else
                    'return value if different
                    If .Cells(i, CurrentArticleColumn) = .Cells(i, NewArticleColumn) Then
                        bCopyRow = False
                    Else
                        bCopyRow = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        
            If bCopyRow = True Then
                startrow = startrow + 1
                .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 9).Copy wsPrint.Cells(startrow, 1)
                .Cells(i, CurrentArticleColumn).Copy wsPrint.Cells(startrow, 10)
                .Cells(i, NewArticleColumn).Copy wsPrint.Cells(startrow, 11)
            End If
        
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        '5. End
    End With
    
    '6 Hide Unnecessary columns
    With Worksheets("RebuildPrintOptima")
        .Range("A:B,D:E,I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        .DisplayPageBreaks = True
        .Select
    End With
    '6 End
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Completed in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs"), vbInformation
End Sub

